# Using libcontainer on LXC

Tags: docker, lxc-docker

I'm trying to run Docker (1.9) on a lxc container. Docker works fine if I use lxc exec driver but fails with libcontainer.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to use libcontainer on lxc?
- If not, why is it so?

I vaguely know it probably doesn't make sense not to use lxc driver on lxc, but I want to understand more details.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't surprising when you see pull request like [PR 17700](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17700):

> ### Remove LXC support
>
> The LXC driver was deprecated in Docker 1.8.
> Following the deprecation rules, we can remove a deprecated feature
> after two major releases.
> LXC won't be supported anymore starting on Docker 1.10.

As I mentioned in "[Difference between LXC and libcontainer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34155329/6309)", libcontainer (or runc now) is supposed to replace and abstract LXC. So "running libcontainer on lxc" doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Docker 1.10 has [removed support](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.10.0) for the LXC execution driver. That doesn't mean that you can't use Docker 1.10 inside of an LXC -- you definitely can.